# CSS transform scalex line unconsistant height

Tags: css, css-transitions, scale, css-transforms

I have a hover animation on a link. A line is drawn below the text. It's 2px in height. the problem is that it starts with one height and continues with another height.

- Why is it doing that? It does not need to calculate anything because 2px is a fixed number.
- How can I get around it?

The animated GIF is taken in Chrome.

[image]

```css
:root {
  --cp-500: #c53e3a;
  --cp-700: #8d1d2d;
  --cp-800: #721228;
}

.action a {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--cp-500), var(--cp-800));
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100vh;
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid var(--cp-700);
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 1.25rem 1rem -1rem var(--cp-800);
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
 }

.action a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 1rem -1rem var(--cp-800);
  background: var(--cp-700);
}

.action a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .5rem;
  left: 2rem;
  width: calc(100% - 4rem);
  height: 2px;
  background: var(--cp-500);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: transform 1000ms ease-in;
  z-index: -1;
}

.action a:hover:before {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
   <a href="#">Test</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's working fine in my computer. =)

Comment: Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it works fine.

Comment: Also fine,79.0.3945.88 on Win10. Font seems to change thought?

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Please share your chrome version and system info.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 - 64 bit on Windows.

Comment: I do use 125% on my screen resolution which may cause it. It's still not correct behaviour because it should not jump between 1 and 2 pixels during the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also able to reproduce your issue. As AlexioVay mentioned above, you should add a scaleY also. But it's not enough, you should set the scaleY to be almost the same as scaleX. Now the line has the same height from the start till the end. See this code: https://jsfiddle.net/q236tmuk/30/

I added the following change to your css:

```
.action a:hover:before {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(0.99);
}
```

The following scenario will also work well:

```
.action a:hover:before {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1.01);
}
```

On hover the line height is the same from the start till the end. Don't use the same value for scaleX and scaleY, because that way the height will change after the transform event. It's a browser issue. The only solution is to use a small different value for scaleY.

Comment: As @AlexioVay came close to the solution I felt something was still missing. I think this answer is a bit better. If I get it right, to avoid a browser bug, we need to have both scaleX and scaleY set to almost the same value, but never exactly the same. That is to force the browser to keep the correct value during the whole transition.

Comment: Yes, you are right, This kind of issues appear for both Chrome and Mozilla for many css settings.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that this behaviour occurs when your browser size is `125%`. I could also reproduce this behaviour and tested a lot, including attributes like `height` and `max-height` which didn't affect anything.

It seems that `scaleX` is the main issue and because you use an increased browser size, this behaviour is only visible in this specific browser size (or a bigger browser size than 125%). So it may also behave like this at 100%, but can't be seen since 2px is too small to see it with the human eye is my guess.

Therefore I have also added `scaleY(1.2)` to `transform:` on `.action a:hover:before` which prevents this jittery behaviour.

```css
:root {
  --cp-500: #c53e3a;
  --cp-700: #8d1d2d;
  --cp-800: #721228;
}

.action a {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--cp-500), var(--cp-800));
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100vh;
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid var(--cp-700);
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 1.25rem 1rem -1rem var(--cp-800);
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
 }

.action a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 1rem -1rem var(--cp-800);
  background: var(--cp-700);
}

.action a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .5rem;
  left: 2rem;
  width: calc(100% - 4rem);
  height: 2px;
  background: var(--cp-500);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: transform 1000ms ease-in;
  z-index: -1;
}

.action a:hover:before {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
   <a href="#">Test</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nice! Is `1.2` a number out of the blue or is there a logical explanation to why that number is used? I wonder what would happen in other resolutions. Will it break? I've tested 100% as well and it seems to work with 100% and 125%.

Comment: I tested some numbers between `1` and `2` and `1.2` provides the best result when the height of the line is 2px. Since `scale` scales an element not depending on pixels, I assume this will work with other height sizes too. Note: You could also write `transform: scale(1, 1.2)` to shorten this solution a little bit.

Comment: Update: The higher the pixels, the more visible the transition. If I set `height` to `20px` and keep `scaleY(1.2)` you clearly see that it's not a straight line. See the following codepen and try to change the `scaleY` value: https://codepen.io/alexiovay/pen/rNaYVym This means you would have to test it depending on the `height` every time to be sure. I would be happy if I could help you out! @JensTörnell